# Inserting symbol before subsection

Tags: macros, symbols

I would like to change the macros on the `\subsection` command, where right before each subsection the symbol `$\blacktriangleright$` is attached.

I have tried

```
\documentclass[twosided, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\blacktriangleright\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

but this has not worked. I get an undefined control sequence error, however, and I do know now that it's because my titlesec package isn't updated. But my MikTex console isn't allowing me to update the package.

Comment: This question will greatly benefit from a detailed account of what you tried, i.e. a minimal example. It is straightforward to format subsections with `titlesec` unless there is some boundary condition, but in order for others to see whether such a boundary condition exists they need to see your attempt(s) in detail.

Comment: Also clarify: Just in the body of the document, or also in the ToC? And is it before the number, into the margin, or between the number and title?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Depending on the packages and `\documentclass` you use, different approaches can be used. The `titlesec` package for example would probably not the best choice if you use a KOMA class ... So, you should really tell us more about your document, preferably by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @user23623 I have updated my post

Comment: @Werner, just the body of the document.

Comment: @Dee: Try with [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/gCTzcrh7); [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkQtR.png).

Comment: @Werner, thank you, that worked :) If you post that as an answer I'll accept it as one

Comment: @Dee: I adjusted the duplicate links to point to another post that was used as inspiration.